# Android KitKat: How to load image from SD Card (path)?

Tags: android, image

I was trying to get image from SD Card which I captured in previous ReportActivity.

This is my code to save image into SD Card directory in ReportActivity.

```
private void SaveIamge(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

    String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    currentPicLoc=root+"/saved_images"+fname;
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    if (file.exists())
        file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    // Tell the media scanner about the new file so that it is
    // immediately available to the user.
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{file.toString()}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                    Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                }
            });
}
```

Then OnActivityResult for capturing a photo.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
      Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (data.hasExtra("data")){
            Bitmap thumbnail =(Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
             buttonLoadImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);

            SaveIamge(thumbnail);



        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }

    }

}
```

Button to go next page.

```
public void onSubmit(View view) {




    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), currentPicLoc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Testing.class);
    intent.putExtra("imageURL",currentPicLoc);
    startActivity(intent);


}
```

Then, I display the image and URL for the image.

onCreate method in next page.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testing);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    String imageURL = extras.getString("imageURL");

    TextView tvMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);

    tvMessage.setText(imageURL);




    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageTesting);

    Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageURL));

    imageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

/*

```
    File file = new File (imageURL);

    imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
```

*/

```
}
```

However the result is i cannot load the image. But the path(String) of the image is displayed.

(I can't display image here as my reputation is below 10)

Please Help!

Comment: tried with other than kitkat ?

Comment: Nope, because I just manage to get an Android KitKat phone.

Comment: no emulators to try upon?

Comment: This task required smartphone features to capture photo. Emulator couldn't helps on this.

Comment: kk cool but can retrieve saved photos know on which you are stuck right now

Comment: I manage to get the path but not able to display the image. I tested quite a few times with the sample code in Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Android 4.4 (KitKat), Google blocked apps from writing to the SD card except for a very specific sandboxed location.

Comment: But i manage to save it into directory (I check gallery and it was there).

Comment: tvMessage (tvMessage) displayed as below:

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/saved_images/Image-2200.jpg

Comment: picture available at that location ? and code retrieving the same url?checked?

Comment: added in manifest ? :  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: I am able to display it !! The problem is currentPicLoc=root+"/saved_images"+fname;

and replace it with 
currentPicLoc=root+"/saved_images/"+fname;

A missing slash! 

I'm sorry to took your time to look for this minor mistake....

Comment: Anyway, Thanks for your help, utility

Comment: pleasure you got result !

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
File imgFile = new  File(imageURL);

if(imgFile.exists()){

    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageTesting);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);

}
```

Comment: Nevermind - you seem to have found the error yourself

Comment: Thanks, but i found the problem where the path "currentPicLoc=root+"/saved_images"+fname" was missing a slash before fname.

However, Thanks a lot.